# R: write list of lists of lists to a text file with names

Tags: r, list, write.table

I have a list of lists of lists with this structure:

```
a = list("t" = list('abc'), "c" = list('def','ghi')) 
b = list("t" = list('jk','kl'), "c" = list('lmn')) 
c = list("t" = list('op','pq','z'), "c" = list('qrs','tuv','wxy'))
ls = list('one'=a,'two'=b,'three'=c)
```

I need to store this in a text file. Since not all elements are the same length, I need to fill with nans before turning it into a dataframe and writing to a file. I want a file that looks something like this (shown roughly as .csv here, but .txt is fine):

```
 t1, t2, t3, c1, c2, c3
one,abc,nan,nan,def,ghi,nan
two,jk,kl,nan,lmn,nan,nan
three,op,pq,z,qrs,tuv,wxy
```

I'm new to R so I only have a general sense of how I might do this and can't figure out the syntax. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
lapply(ls, fill nans)
lapply(ls, unlist)
lapply(ls, names=[t1,t2,t3,c1,c2,c3])
df=data.frame(ls)
write.table(df)
```

Can someone walk me through this?

edit: I was able to make some progress with:

```
ellength <- function(ls,i) {return(length(ls[[i]]))}

fillna <- function(ls,i,m) {
if (length(ls[[i]])<m) {
return(append(ls[[i]],vector('list',length=m-length(ls[[i]]))))
}
else {return(ls[[i]])}
}

make_col <- function(ls,i){
return(lapply(ls,fillna,i=i,m=max(unlist(lapply(ls,ellength,i=i)))))
}

> matrix(list(make_col(ls,'t'),make_col(ls,'c')))
     [,1]  
[1,] List,3
[2,] List,3
```

But I still can't write this to a file in any coherent way. This is so simple to do in Python; I must be missing something. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help at all?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
a = list("t" = 'abc', "c" = list('def','ghi')) 
b = list("t" = 'jk', "c" = list('lmn')) 
c = list("t" = 'op', "c" = list('qrs','tuv','wxy'))
ls = list('one'=a,'two'=b,'three'=c)
#unlist and turn into a df
lx <- as.data.frame( unlist(ls),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#make rownames as column
lx$nms <- rownames(lx)

#split nms column so you can transpose your data
lx <- separate(lx, nms, c("v1","v2"), sep = "[.]")
lx <- mutate(lx, v3 = `unlist(ls)`) %>% 
      select(-`unlist(ls)`)
#transpose your data - it fills with NA
#NaN is a numeric field so you can't use it to fill character variables
lx2 <- spread(lx,v2,v3)
```

## update

If you want to collapse over variables you can use `ifelse` to replace `NA`s in certain columns:

```
lx2 <- mutate(lx2, c_1 = ifelse(is.na(c),c1,c))
lx2 <- mutate(lx2, t_1 = ifelse(is.na(t),t1,t))
lx3 <- lx2[c('v1','c_1','c2','c3','t_1','t2','t3')]
```

Comment: ok so now I have:
> lx2
     v1    c   c1   c2   c3    t   t1   t2   t3
1   one <NA>  def  ghi <NA>  abc <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 three <NA>  qrs  tuv  wxy <NA>   op   pq    z
3   two  lmn <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   jk   kl <NA>
how do I collapse c with c1 and t with t1?

Comment: you can use `ifelse` to collapse over c and c1, I will update my answer to show an example

Comment: worked for c, but didn't work when I did: lx2 <- mutate(lx2, t_1 = ifelse(is.na(c),t1,t))
(I had edited the example list in my OP)

Comment: I believe you have to change `is.na(c)` to `is.na(t)` like this:  lx2 <- mutate(lx2, t_1 = ifelse(is.na(t),t1,t))

Comment: yep, you're right, I just realized and was about to comment the same

Comment: maybe add those two lines to your answer, plus: lx2 <- lx2[c('v1','c_1','c2','c3','t_1','t2','t3')] for clarity

Comment: I added the lines and selected the columns you requested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182112/discussion-between-andbeonetraveler-and-mike).

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a list of data frames after unlisting the nested list:

```
char_vec <- unlist(ls)

df_list <- lapply(names(ls), function(x) {
  tmp <- data.frame(t(char_vec[names(char_vec)[grep(x, names(char_vec))]]),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(tmp) <- gsub(".*\\.", "", names(tmp))

  return(tmp)
})

df_list
# [[1]]
#     t  c1  c2
# 1 abc def ghi

# [[2]]
#   t1 t2   c
# 1 jk kl lmn

# [[3]]
#   t1 t2 t3  c1  c2  c3
# 1 op pq  z qrs tuv wxy
```

To bind all data frame items together, you can use `dplyr`, `data.table`, or even `base` R:

**dplyr** *(with `bind_rows`)*

```
final_df1 <- bind_rows(df_list)

# CLEAN UP AND RE-ORDER COLUMNS
final_df1 <- transform(final_df1, 
                       t1 = ifelse(is.na(t), t1, t),
                       t = NULL,
                       c1 = ifelse(is.na(c), c1, c),
                       c = NULL
              )

final_df1 <- final_df1[order(names(final_df1))]
```

**data.table** *(with `rbindlist`)*

```
final_df2 <- data.frame(rbindlist(df_list, fill=TRUE))

# CLEAN UP AND RE-ORDER COLUMNS
final_df2 <- transform(final_df2, 
                       t1 = ifelse(is.na(t), t1, t),
                       t = NULL,
                       c1 = ifelse(is.na(c), c1, c),
                       c = NULL
              )

final_df2 <- final_df2[order(names(final_df2))]
```

**base** R *(with `do.call`)*

```
# RETRIEVE ALL COLUMN NAMES
nms <- names(unlist(df_list))

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(df){
  # CREATE BLANK COLUMNS FOR rbind
  for(i in nms) {
    if(!i %in% names(df)) {
      df[[i]] <- NA
    }
  }

  # CLEAN UP AND RE-ORDER COLUMNS
  df <- within(df, {t1 <- ifelse(is.na(t), t1, t)
                    t <- NULL
                    c1 <- ifelse(is.na(c), c1, c)
                    c <- NULL
        })

  return(df[order(names(df))])
})

final_df3 <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

**Output**

```
final_df1
#    c1   c2   c3  t1   t2   t3
# 1 def  ghi <NA> abc <NA> <NA>
# 2 lmn <NA> <NA>  jk   kl <NA>
# 3 qrs  tuv  wxy  op   pq    z

identical(final_df1, final_df2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(final_df1, final_df3)
# [1] TRUE
identical(final_df2, final_df3)
# [1] TRUE
```